# T-SQL: How to convert string representations of a date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got some dates stored in varchar(10) format.

Dates are like so:

```
2008-01-06
2008-01-13
2008-01-20
2008-01-27
2008-02-03
2008-02-10
2008-02-17
2008-02-24
```

I would like them in dd/mm/yyyy format (also a DATE datatype)

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), startWeek, 103) date
FROM dbo.GoogledataFinal
```

Why does this output:

```
2008-01-06
2008-01-13
2008-01-20
2008-01-27
2008-02-03
2008-02-10
2008-02-17
```

Would be great if you could fix my code, but I'm more interested in WHY this behaviour is happening, so explaining like I'm 5 years old might be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You are converting from `varchar` to `varchar`.  The style parameter is not even used for that.

Instead, convert to `date`, and then back to `varchar`:

```
select convert(varchar(10), cast('2008-01-06' as datetime), 103)
```

This prints:

```
06/01/2008
```

Comment: Many thanks, I always hated working with dates in SQL... Wondered what the differences with cast and convert where but this helps. Problem is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @waller `convert` allows you to pass a formatting mask, which is important to handle strings representing dates.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, startWeek), 103) date
FROM dbo.GoogledataFinal
```

Comment: you should really include a length on your `varchar`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT (SUBSTRING (startWeek,9, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING (startWeek,6, 2) + '/' SUBSTRING (startWeek,1, 4))  AS date
FROM dbo.GoogledataFinal
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the varchar to a datetime, and then back to varchar using the desired format:

```
SELECT CONVERT( varchar(10), 
         CONVERT(DATETIME, '2008-02-03', 120) -- Varchar "yyyy-mm-dd" to Datetime
       , 103) -- Datetime to Varchar "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

For your case the SQL might be:

```
SELECT CONVERT( varchar(10), 
         CONVERT(DATETIME, startWeek, 120)
       , 103)
FROM dbo.GoogledataFinal
```